# Obtener nombre del mes en español

Tags: php, html, date

Quiero obtener el nombre del mes segun una fecha guardada en MYSQL para ponerla en una columna. Tengo un ejemplo pero lo regresa en inglés:

```
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
echo $monthName;
```

En este caso regresaria **March** y quiero que sea **Marzo** lo que regrese.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Puedes revisar esta pregunta de SO en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845554/php-date-get-name-of-the-months-in-local-language

Comment: Mira esto: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php. También se me ocurre que podrías hacer un switch para cambiar los nombres de inglés a español.

Comment: Y no habra una forma de traducir el mes que regresa el ejemplo que tengo?

Comment: Si quieres traducirlo tú mismo haz un `switch` que dependiendo del mes que te de(en ingles) se almacene otra variable con ese mes traducido al español

Comment: mira esto: https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2016/04/30/convertir-fechas-de-php-a-castellano/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pudes utilizar [`strftime()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) que imprime las fechas basadas en el locale, para esto debes asignarle el locale desado si no lo has hecho antes de esta forma

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
```

Donde `'es_ES'` es el locale de tu preferencia, o puede ser el del usuario, por último el ejemplo adaptado a tu código:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = strftime('%B', $dateObj->getTimestamp());
echo $monthName;
```

Imprimirá `marzo`

---

Creo que es importante mencionar que [`setlocale()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) recibe dos parámetros, la categoría y la localización, si tan solo deseas que las fechas y el tiempo se muestren traducidas puedes utilizar la categoría `LC_TIME`

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = strftime('%B', $dateObj->getTimestamp());
echo $monthName;
```

Lo que nos imprimirá `marzo`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias amigo

Comment: igual si tienes la base de datos alli te recomiendo tambien cambiar la hora y la region donde perteneces al servidor

Comment: Tuve que poner esto para que funcionara `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_CO.UTF-8');`

Answer (score 1):

Ignoro si hay una función para mostrar los datos en español como lo pides, pero puedes traducirlo con un switch.
Desde tu variable `$monthName`

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
echo $monthName;

switch($monthName)
{   
    case "January":
    $monthNameSpanish = "Enero";
    break;

    case "February":
    $monthNameSpanish = "Febrero";
    break;

    case "March":
    $monthNameSpanish = "Marzo";
    break;

    ...
}
echo $monthNameSpanish;
?>
```

O bien, directamente desde tu variable `$monthNum`:

```
<?php
$monthNum  = 1;

switch($monthNum)
{   
    case 1:
    $monthNameSpanish = "Enero";
    break;

    case 2:
    $monthNameSpanish = "Febrero";
    break;

    case 3:
    $monthNameSpanish = "Marzo";
    break;

    //...
}
echo $monthNameSpanish;
?>
```